# Event Name for dynamically loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using select2 to select multiple items on a webpage

I have div loaded dynamically on page from ajax call.

dynamically loaded div::

```
<div class="select2" multiple="multiple">
 <option>Mango</option>
 <option>Banana</option>
 <option>Apple</option>
</div>
```

I have a js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select2").select2({
       placeholder: "select fruits"
     });
});
```

I know this wont work because the div with select2 class is not present while loading the page initially (it is added by ajax later).

I have tried to make it work using

```
 $(document).on(eventname,'.select2',function() {
     $(".select2").select2({
       placeholder: "select fruits"
     });
});
```

I tried the event names load,change. I am not able to make the multi select because i am giving wrong event name. Can some one tell me what the event name exactly is.

Comment: Why not apply select2 when the data is inserted?

Comment: If you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0):

You can manually keep track with a flag attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select2").select2({
       placeholder: "select fruits"
     });
     $(".select2").attr('data-has-select', 1);
});
```

and

```
 $(document).on('click', '.select2', function() {
     if (!$(this).attr('data-has-select')) {
         $(this).select2({
             placeholder: "select fruits"
         });
         $(this).attr('data-has-select', 1);
     }
 });
```